# How to read AD displayname

Tags: delphi, active-directory, pascal

I am using Delphi pascal ver. 4
I have a user initials and need to get the active directory display name from the initials
so I do not want to change AD just read - a function will be nice like this:

```
fullname, user :string;
user:='DKTB'
```

(call function)

```
fullname:=getAdDispayName(user);
```

(after call then fullname = 'Torben Bagge')

I have used google to find it but was only able to find it in C and not pascal.

Comment: First I would download [`JEDI JWSCL`](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/security-library/) (SourceForge seems to be broken somehow at this time), that contains the `JwaActiveDS` unit, which has all things necessary for working with AD. Then I would try to translate code like [`this`](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?474513-Visual-C-General-How-to-get-user-details-from-Active-Directory).

Comment: @TLama: +1 for mentioning Jwa/Jwscl! The mentioned sample code uses an enumerator to find the account which may take a very long time in a large AD Environment. For this kind of operation IDirectorySearch is a better choice!

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this using the IDirectorySearch Interface. I made an quick example for you (don't forget to add proper error handling):

```
uses
  ActiveX,
  JwaAdsTlb, JwaActiveDS; // From Jedi ApiLib

function GetADDisplayName(const Username: String): String;
var
  hr: HRESULT;
  DirSearch: IDirectorySearch;
  SearchInfo: ADS_SEARCHPREF_INFO;
  hSearch: ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE;
  col: ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN;
  Filter: String;
  Attributes: array of PChar;
begin
  Result := 'Undefined Result';

  // Initialize COM
  CoInitialize(nil);

  try
    // Change line below with your domain name
    hr := ADsGetObject('LDAP://dc=contoso,dc=com',
      IID_IDirectorySearch, Pointer(DirSearch));
    Win32Check(Succeeded(hr));

    SearchInfo.dwSearchPref := ADS_SEARCHPREF_SEARCH_SCOPE;
    SearchInfo.vValue.dwType := ADSTYPE_INTEGER;
    SearchInfo.vValue.Integer := ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE;

    hr := DirSearch.SetSearchPreference(@SearchInfo, 1);
    Win32Check(Succeeded(hr));

    Filter := Format('(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))',
      [Username]);

    SetLength(Attributes, 1);
    Attributes[0] := 'displayName';

    // When using Dynamic Array with WinApi ALWAYS use pointer to first element!
    hr := DirSearch.ExecuteSearch(PChar(Filter), @Attributes[0],
      Length(Attributes), hSearch);
    Win32Check(Succeeded(hr));

    try
      hr := DirSearch.GetFirstRow(hSearch);
      Win32Check(Succeeded(hr));

      hr := DirSearch.GetColumn(hSearch, Attributes[0], col);
      if Succeeded(hr) then
      begin
        Result := col.pADsValues^.CaseIgnoreString;
        DirSearch.FreeColumn(@col);
      end;
    finally
      DirSearch.CloseSearchHandle(hSearch);
    end;
  finally
    // UnInitialize COM
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```